# uncorrelated gaussian random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X_1$, ... $X_n$ be gaussian and such that $Cov(X_i,X_j)=0$ for every $i,j \leq n$. Then the $n$-dimensional vector $[X_1, ... X_n]$ is gaussian?

Comment: Yes............

Comment: I don't think this needs that those random variable are uncorrelated. You can even specifically calculated the mutlidimensional gaussian.

Comment: @Chaos. I see. I think I confused something. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general no: take $N$ standard normal and $\varepsilon$ a random variable independent of $N$ taking the values $1$ and $-1$ with probability $1/2$. Let $X_1=N$ and $X_2=N\varepsilon$. Then $X_1$ and $X_2$ have a standard normal distribution and are uncorrelated. But $X_1+X_2=N(1+\varepsilon)$ is not Gaussian, as it takes the value $0$ with probability $1/2$.